# Break vector into pieces and parallelly applying function on them in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, vectorization

I am new to matlab and I do not know how to vectorize the following:

I have a large vector (think 30000) and I want to partition it into pieces of unequal length, specified by row indices into the vector. I have a function, which I want to apply to said peices parallelly(using parfor or otherwise), and stitch back the results.

Is there an efficient way to do this? any pointers will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run `parpool` to initialize a parallel pool in MATLAB (you need the parallel processing toolbox) to get some workers. Then use `parfor` to run a for loop in parallel by having each worker execute the loop at the same time. There are a few rules, such as each iteration in the loop cannot depend on or use results from the previous iteration.

Consider the following code:

```
% Run parpool first

n = 100000;
data = (1:n)';

myIndices = 1:5:n;
numSections = length(myIndices) -1;

f = @(x) mean(x);
outputMatrix = zeros(numSections,1);

% TRy changing this to parfor or just for and run a few times to see
% average time:

tic
parfor ind  = 1:numSections

    if ind == 1
       myStart = 1;
    else
       myStart = myIndices(ind)+1;
     end
    myEnd = myIndices(ind+1);

    outputCell{ind} = f(data(myStart:myEnd));
    outputMatrix(ind) = f(data(myStart:myEnd));
end
toc

% convert cell array to matrix
output = cell2mat(outputCell);
```

Here I show how to collect in a cell or a vector/matrix. It depends on what kind of function you are running on your data. **Try changing the parfor to for and running a few times to see the speed difference.**

I chose to divide the data into even blocks of size 5 but you could change this to be whatever you want by making `myIndices` be arbitrary values.